# FURLS with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing a website with many pages whose content will be fetched from database. The whole website is done in codeigniter.

I do not want to have url's like www.mywebsite.com/pages/1 or something.
Rather I would like to have url name (FURL) asked by the administrator at the time of entering the contents of the page. Suppose the admin enters FURL as : study-programs/animation
then the path should be shown as www.mywebsity.com/study-programs/animation

Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean the user enters a category type of classification? I don't know why users would enter text like `study-programs/animation/cgi/smurfs` as a path, you should just have them select categories/sub categories and build a path for THEM.

Answer (score 0):

1) Foreach page store the page name (could use **uri_title()**)

2) In the routes (*application/config/routes*) add something like;

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = "pages/page_lookup";
```

3) In the pages controller;

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function page_lookup($page) {
        // do your database query getting page id where page name = $page
        $result = $this->page_model->get_page_by_name($page);

        // $result could hold the page html
        // if so, then just do
        $this->load->view($result);
    }
}
```

For  more details look at the [examples](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) in the Codeigniter manual.

Comment: this approach will still have the url's as pages/page_lookup and when clicked it will be redirected to a new URL. Can there be a approach which generates url's directly with the page names?