# CodeIgniter custom universal Router class

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to "shorten" my URLs, for example from:

```
http://mydomain.com/controller/method/something-here
```

into

```
http://mydomain.com/something-here
```

by adding to `routes.php`:

```
$route['(.*)'] = 'router/resolve/$1';
```

and creating a `Router` class, whose `resolve()` method determines whether `something-here` matches a row in one of my database tables (entities). If so, I want to load the entry by calling the appropriate controller::method.

For example, if `something-here` is a type of `book`, I'd like `Router::resolve()` to call `Book::view($id)`.

However, I realize it's not possible for a controller to call the method of another controller. (Is it?)

I also cannot use `redirect("book/view/$id")` because `$route['(.*)']` will call `Router::resolve()` on `book` (the first segment).

Any suggestions on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: why not just use a redirect controller, something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845440/furls-with-codeigniter/10845725#10845725

Comment: It still uses some `text/` before `something-here`. I'd like to have the URL be `something-here` right after the domain.

Comment: sorry, misread the problem; calling a controller from another. The best solution for you that I can think of is HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions;
1) Use a [HMVC architecture](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/), which would allow for calling one controller from another.

2) Dynamically generate your routes.
This may not be the most efficient or elegant solution, but it is an option.

```
<?php
$route[ 'default_controller' ]  = 'main';
$route[ '404_override' ]        = 'error404';

require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'whatever_table' );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[$row->slug.'/(:any)'] = $row->controller.'/'.$row->method.'/$1';
}
```

As it has been pointed out to me before, routes are processed using a regex (in `_parse_routes`) so this may not be the quickest in performance, it depends on how many routes you would be generating and how you feel about the performance impact.